# How to prevent word breaking with using text-overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a max number of rows for some headlines, but the problem is that sometimes a row will end with a broken word. what i need is that if a word would have to break, it should be hidden completely, and the ellipses placed after the previous word.

this code shows the issue:

```css
#head {
    width:300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4 !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div id="head">

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a


</div>

</html>
```

the word "ever" is broken in the middle, can i somehow prevent this from happening?

Comment: You would probably need some sort of a js solution for this as I don't think you can tell css to clip the whole of the last word

Comment: funny thing: this, of course is just an example, what i am getting is sometimes a word that doesnt have space to be shown on its line is hidden completely and sometimes it gets clipped in the middle, like in the example...